# Timeout error when trying to install python packages

Tags: python, pip, ping

I've been using Python lately, but I can't install packages on my Windows 10 machine. Whenever I try to install any new package I get the following error:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after 
connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed 
out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/[module name]/
```

I tried pinging pypi.org a few times, and I usually have only a 25-75% success rate.

```
Pinging pypi.org [2a04:4e42::223] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 2a04:4e42::223: time=214ms
Reply from 2a04:4e42::223: time=214ms
Request timed out.
Reply from 2a04:4e42::223: time=214ms

Ping statistics for 2a04:4e42::223:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 3, Lost = 1 (25% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 214ms, Maximum = 214ms, Average = 214ms
```

I also have Ubuntu running on a virtual machine and I haven't had any problems downloading modules, so I figure it isn't a hardware issure. I am using an un-activated Windows 10, could that be the problem?

Versions:
python 3.9.2
pip 20.2.3

Comment: upgrade it to last version

Comment: I already reinstalled python and pip, versions:
python 3.9.2
pip 20.2.3

Comment: The latest version of pip is 21.0.1, not 20.2.3

Comment: I tried updating pip in the python directory with the following command:

...
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
...

but I still get the same TimeoutError.